# Updating property type and value in a MongoDB document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a Node.js application to keep an inventory of books and am using MongoDB and mongoose.

When I first modeled my Schema, there was a `genre` field of type `String` which held a single value; **in other words, a book could only be assigned one genre.**

After adding some "books" into my database, **I decided to make a slight change to the Schema design and updated the** `genre` **field to** `genres` **so that I could instead have an** `Array` **of strings**. Now every new document I add into the database has a `genres` field of type `Array`, but *now I'm wondering how to update the documents in the database* which reflect the design of the earlier model.

I've started to write a script that:

1. Iterates through documents in the database where the field `genre` (singular) exists,
2. Updates the field name to `genres` AND sets its value to an array containing whatever value the previous `genre` property was equal to.

So for instance, (for simplicity's sake I'll use an object with a single property of genre), from this:

```
{genre: "Philosophy"}
```

I'm trying to get to this

```
{genres: ["Philosophy"]}
```

**How can I achieve this?**
This is the code I have so far

```
db.books.updateMany({genre: {$exists: true}},{<missing this part>}
```

Comment: You dont want to updateOne. You want to update many

Comment: Sorry, that's confusing. I'm doing some testing through the mongo shell and working with a single book. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to iterate over every element in your db:

```
 db.books.find({genre: {$exists: true}}).forEach(doc => {
```

Then you want to update that element:

```
 if(Array.isArray(doc.genre)) return;

 db.books.updateOne(doc, { $set: { genre:[doc.genre]} });
```

Comment: That worked! (expect I did doc.genre). But how do I change the property name from genre to genres?

Comment: ahh, I see... so there seems to be no way of renaming the field without setting and unsetting it. I found a `$rename` operator in the mongodb query language which achieves the same end, but under the hood it performs a set and an unset, thus altering the order of the fields in the document. This may be an entirely separate question,but can you think of a way to preserve (or rearrange) the order of fields in the document?

Comment: @jaySeeCode no im not shire about that. Make shure to aclnowledge mickls answer, it seems promising

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation framework to do that:

```
db.books.aggregate([
    { $match: { genre: { $exists: true } } },
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            genres: { $push: "$genre" },
            fst: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
        } 
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$fst",  "$$ROOT" ] } }
    },
    { $project: { fst: 0, genre: 0 } },
    { $out: "books" }
])
```

$group is a way of transforming property to an array (each group will contain only one element since we're grouping by unique `_id`). Using $replaceRoot with [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) you can merge all your properties from original object with your new array. Then you need to remove unnecessary fields using $project. Last step which is [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) will redirect the output of this aggregation into specified collection, causing updates in this case.

Comment: do you know if this solution will alter the order of fields in the document?

Comment: thank you for you answer @mickls. I'm working on understanding all parts of this code. what does  `fst: { $first: "$$ROOT" }` do/mean?

Comment: $$ROOT is a special variable in MongoDB which represents currently processed document (entire).  $first represents first document matched by grouping key (it is a special operator dedicated for $group. We're doing this because we want to keep entire original document and add an array of genres. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I ran your suggestion and it did work. However, I don't fully understand how the aggregation framework works yet, so I'll be looking into it more in depth. Thanks for that too!